# How to render JSON in React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON object of some random numbers. Initially, I get an empty object, but then it gets updated through props.

```
summary: {
    numbers: {"123": 45,"678": 9,"101": 11},
    other-stuff: "some other stuff"
}
```

I want to render numbers something like this,

```
123 => 45
678 => 9
101 => 11
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
getNumbers() {
    if (this.props.summary.numbers) {
        return this.props.summary.numbers.map( (num, key) => {
            return <p>{key} => {num}</p>;
        });
    } else {
        return <p>data is not available</p>;
    }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>{this.getNumbers}</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` function is for arrays but `this.props.summary.numbers` is an object. Consider using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function

```
getNumbers() {
    if (this.props.summary.numbers) {
        return Object.keys(this.props.summary.numbers).map( (key) => {
            return <p>{key} => {this.props.summary.numbers[key]}</p>;
        });
    } else {
        return <p>data is not available</p>;
    }
}
```

Also you need to call the `getNumbers` function inside `render` function

```
<div>{this.getNumbers()}</div>
```

Comment: Am I rendering it properly?
`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: @HafizTemuri Check update

Answer (score 3):

```
getNumbers() {
    if (this.props.summary.numbers) {
        return Object.keys(this.props.summary.numbers).map( (key) => {
            return <p>{key} => {this.props.summary.numbers[key]}</p>;
        });
    } else {
        return <p>data is not available</p>;
    }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>{this.getNumbers()}</div>
    );
}
```

2 things which you did wrong
a) You didn't call the function.
b) You used maps over object.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now :)